# Inconsistent datatype in cast

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, blob, clob

I have the following SQL query which I have to convert into Oracle query:

```
select binaryPhotoNumber, cast(cast(PhotoInfo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) as PhotoInfo
From ProfilePictures
Where profilesourceid = 10
```

I tried converting it to Oracle and the result is following

```
select binaryPhotoNumber, cast(cast(PhotoInfo as BLOB) as CLOB) as PhotoInfo
From ProfilePictures
Where profilesourceid = 10
```

However, I'm getting an error

> Inconsistent datatypes: expected -got BLOB.

DDL:

```
binaryPhotoNumber is Number

PhotoInfo is BLOB

profilesourceid is Number
```

Now that I got to know that PhotoInfo is BLOB so, I changed my query to the following

```
select binaryPhotoNumber, cast(PhotoInfo as CLOB) as PhotoInfo
    From ProfilePictures
    Where profilesourceid = 10
```

Now it gives me

> Inconsistent datatypes: expected -got CLOB.

Comment: Please add the ddl of the table? And cast does nt support LOBs as a target, here's what the [21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75) manual says: CAST does not directly support any of the LOB data types. When you use CAST to convert a CLOB value into a character data type or a BLOB value into the RAW data type, the database implicitly converts the LOB value to character or raw data and then explicitly casts the resulting value into the target data type.....

Comment: @gsalem i updated my question and added the details

Comment: I think probably `to_clob(PhotoInfo)` is your best bet, but see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849025/convert-blob-to-clob)

Comment: @kfinity now it says, expected char got blob

Comment: Straight from the documentation: ***CAST does not directly support any of the LOB data types.*** You can try `to_clob(to_blob(whatever))` (assuming it makes sense; to me it doesn't - what's wrong with leaving the result as a BLOB? Why do you need to then convert it to CLOB?)

Comment: @mathguy the content in the blob field is xml data and when i simple display the value as it is it just gives me (BLOB) for all records.

Comment: If it's valid XML data, does `xmltype(photoinfo, 0)` or `xmltype(photoinfo, 0).getclobval()` give you what you need? (Where the 0 denotes the database character set ID; you might need to specify a valid CSID for the actual data...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's XML data you can convert it to an XMLType with:

```
xmltype(photoinfo, 0)
```

to use the database character set, or to specify the character set (likely to be UTF-8, but might not be) you can specify that with:

```
xmltype(photoinfo, nls_charset_id('UTF8'))
```

Once you have it as that data type you can manipulate it as XML, with function like XMLQuery and XMLTable ([read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4805CF1C-A00D-4B88-AF2E-00A9DB6F3392)); or to just see the whole thing as a CLOB you can do:

```
xmltype(photoinfo, nls_charset_id('UTF8')).getclobval()
```