# How do I convert an Oracle SQL BLOB into a read-only text?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-06512

I need to provide some log messages to a person: for me as an admin that is just point and click stuff, but for this person is not possible unless I can extract and convert a blob and deliver that in the moment the sql process ends... problem is this is a factory code, I can only expose its boot and not the code itself,  so i cannot even manipulate code and add a procedure to set this blob conversion as "part two";
besides, the person can only execute one file at a time and only in 3 (THREE) cases I actually need to convert the blob, since these three cases (for strange internal reasons) cannot be handled, do you think theres another way?

I know where tables and columns are, I know their names and can easily extract those as normal blobs, all the oracle functions I used give me the error ORA-06512, sometimes our system instead tells me it was expecting a number but got a blob(?).

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table(s); the `INSERT` statement for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output. You have given us a convoluted explanation of the problem but no way to replicate it; we need a way to replicate the problem if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [How to convert BLOB to CLOB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12849025/1509264)